# How do I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin on upstream errors in nginx?

Tags: nginx, cors

I know there are a million answers to "how to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in nginx" but unfortunately if there's an answer to my specific question, it's buried with all the basic answers.

I have an Angular app pointing to an nginx server with a rest service upstream - all running on my local laptop inside a docker compose.

The nginx service is configured fairly simply:

```
    upstream REST {
       # rest-service is mapped by docker-compose to the correct container
       server rest-service:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        # This is mapped in /etc/hosts on my laptop
        server_name rest-api.mylocal.com;

        location / {
            proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
            # web-ui is also mapped in /etc/hosts on my laptop
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "http://web-ui.mylocal.com";

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000; # 20 days
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';

            add_header Reverse-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host            $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://REST;
        }
    }
```

If I call a valid URL on the rest service, e.g. `http://rest-api.mylocal.com/api/v1/auth/config` (this is an unauthenticated endpoint), everything works as expected:

```
curl -v 'http://rest-api.mylocal.com/api/v1/auth/config'
...
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://web-ui.mylocal.com
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
< Reverse-Proxy: true
<
* Connection #0 to host rest-api.mylocal.com left intact
{"status":"OK","name":"foo",...}* Closing connection 0
```

However, if I call an invalid URL, say `http://rest-api.mylocal.com/api/v1/accounts` (which is an authenticated endpoint, and I provide no credentials), I get back the expected error, but there are no CORS headers.  In a browser this causes everything to flake out so I don't even get the error message in Angular to display to the user:

```
curl -v 'http://rest-api.mylocal.com/api/v1/accounts'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to rest-api.mylocal.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/accounts HTTP/1.1
> Host: rest-api.mylocal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403
< Server: nginx/1.21.6
< Date: Wed, 09 Feb 2022 20:57:49 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F3B21A55841C8E5A6F838F2427A0E22B; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
<
* Connection #0 to host rest-api.mylocal.com left intact
{"timestamp":"2022-02-09T20:57:49.526+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/api/v1/accounts"}* Closing connection 0
```

Browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://rest-api.mylocal.com/api/v1/accounts' from origin 'http://web-ui.mylocal.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So... Is there a way to make sure the CORS headers are still added to the response by nginx even if the response from the upstream server is an error (401/403/404/etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `always` to each header you want added to error responses.  It was added in 1.7.5: https://nginx.org/r/add_header